# On Navigation Drawer back button is not working correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back-button

[Fragment Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNLfl.png)

I have 5 fragments.On pressing back button  I want to move to home fragment no matter how many fragments are opened.

If I move from

[1] --> [2] and Press back [1] shown home fragment

[1] --> [3] and Press back [1] shown home fragment

[1] --> [4] and Press back [1] shown home fragment

[1] --> [5] and Press back [1] shown home fragment

As I want No Problem.

But Problem is

[1] --> [2] --> [3] and Press back home fragment overlap on [3]

[1] --> [2] --> [4] and Press back home fragment overlap on [4]

[1] --> [2] --> [5] and Press back home fragment overlap on [5]

I have added only home fragment to backStack and used replace fragment method.

Why this is happening???

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.all_activity_layout);
>     setToolbar();
>     addFragment(AttractionsFragment.newInstance());
>     setNavigationDrawer();
> }
>
>  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
>  @Override
>  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     switch (item.getItemId()) {
>         case R.id.nav_attractions:
>             if (mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem != 0) {
>                 mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem = 0;
>                 replaceFragment(AttractionsFragment.newInstance());
>             }
>             break;
>         case R.id.nav_packages:
>             if (mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem != 1) {
>                 mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem = 1;
>                 replaceFragment(PackagesFragment.newInstance());
>             }
>             break;
>         case R.id.nav_passes:
>             if (mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem != 2) {
>                 mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem = 2;
>                 replaceFragment(PassesFragment.newInstance());
>
>             }
>             break;
>         case R.id.nav_coupons:
>             if (mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem != 3) {
>                 mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem = 3;
>                 replaceFragment(CouponsFragment.newInstance());
>
>             }
>             break;
>         case R.id.nav_more:
>             if (mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem != 4) {
>                 mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem = 4;
>                 replaceFragment(MoreFragment.newInstance());
>             }
>             break;
>     }
>
>     mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(mCurrentNavigationDrawerItem).setChecked(true);
>
>     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>     return true;
> }
>
> public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
>     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>
>     // Get Current Visible fragment
>     Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
>     // Add to back stack only if it is AttractionsFragment
>     if (f instanceof AttractionsFragment) {
>         transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
>     }
>
>     transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
>     transaction.commit();
>
>     Log.d("Navigation", "BackStack Count:" + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
>
>
> }
>
> public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
>     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>     transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "AttractionsFragment");
>     transaction.commit();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
>         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>     } else {
>         super.onBackPressed();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Why are you adding fragment to backstack?

Comment: Remove the   transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName()); line it will work fine

Comment: Because on pressing back I want to move to my home fragment.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pop the 2nd fragment before navigating to 3rd fragment.

```
  Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    // Add to back stack only if it is AttractionsFragment
    if (f instanceof AttractionsFragment) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    } else {
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the code but it closed the app. Please tell me why should I pop. I am only add the home fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());` line it will work fine. Please check the code below

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Get Current Visible fragment
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
// Add to back stack only if it is AttractionsFragment

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();

Log.d("Navigation", "BackStack Count:" + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());


 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. By removing that line  on pressing back button my app finished

Comment: But I want to move to my Home fragment.

Comment: While adding to the first fragment use addToBackStack other wise remove that

Comment: transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName()); This with transaction.addtoBackStack(null);

Answer (score 0):

Replace your container view with first fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new **your_first_fragment**()).commit();

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does remove overlapping but at the same time close app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding/launching all three fragments in the same activity, instead of the add() method of FragmentTransaction for showing Fragment3, use the replace() method of FragmentTransaction (replace Fragment2 with Fragment3). The replace method removes the current fragment from backstack before adding the new fragment. If you are launching Fragment3 from a different activity, and thus you can't/don't want to use replace(), remove Fragment2 from backstack before starting the new activity (which adds fragment3):

```
// in Fragment2, before adding Fragment3:
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .remove(this) // "this" refers to current instance of Fragment2
               .commit();
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
// now go ahead and launch (add) fragment3
// if fragment3 is launched from a different activity, 
// start that activity instead
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.a_container_view_in_activity, new Fragment3(),
                    Fargment3.FRAGMENT3_ID)
               .commit();
```

This will solve your problem. Try this..

Comment: In replace fragment , you are replacing your fragment. You add these codes in in your `MainActivty`(in which activity your are adding your fragments) in `onBackPressed()` method.This will remove your fragments from backstack.

Comment: Which fragment is (myFrag) as I have 5 fragments. thanks

Comment: see my edited code and do changes in your fragment where you are adding your next fragment.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I am replacing all fragment in one activity.

Comment: Why when I press back the fragment is shown on back even I am not adding it to back stack.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in your `onBackPressed`:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

also in your replace fragment- to solve overlapping issue try

```
transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), fragment);
```

or

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new FirstFragment()).commit();
```

Try changing your code in replace fragment:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Get Current Visible fragment
    //Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    AttractionsFragment myFragment = (AttractionsFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
    if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
        // Add to back stack only if it is AttractionsFragment
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "MY_FRAGMENT");
    transaction.commit();

    Log.d("Navigation", "BackStack Count:" + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tested this code but. It does not solve the problem. I need to press back button twice and then the app is closed. but does not move to home fragment

Comment: @prince11786 try the edited replace fragment code also check logcat on onBackpressed() method

Comment: Thanks @rafsanahmad007 Still same problem. I have checked the home fragment is added to the back stack. But When back button is pressed the last fragment is not removed and home fragment is shown on the top of that.

Comment: NO! I am facing the same problem which I was facing before even after adding the above code. Home Fragment is overlapped on the previous fragment.

Comment: I think by add your condition or mine the home fragment is added to the backStack. But problem is on pressing back button the previous fragment is not removed and the backStacked fragment is shown above of it.

Comment: Yes I have tried that But that does not worked for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `OnBackpress` add this code:

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_container) instanceof HomeFragment) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                } else {
                        replaceFragment(this, new HomeFragment());
                    }
                }
```

And change your `replaceFragment` and `AddFragment` methods in all cases with the code given below:

```
 public void addFragment(final Activity mActivity, final Fragment newFragment, final Fragment hideFragment) {
            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.hide(hideFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_container, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(hideFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
public void replaceFragment(final Activity mActivity, final Fragment newFragment) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_container, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Where `activity_container` is the `FrameLayout` Id in xml file of the activity.

In `onCreate` of your activity call `replaceFragment` method instead of `addFragment`. And in all navigation item click event, call `replaceFragment` method.